# Notation on Continuity Eqn Derivation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, mass-transfer

Was reviewing some notes on fluid dynamics, and the notes go as follows (conservation of mass for a qubic CV),
$$\frac{dm_{out}}{dt} = \rho u (dydz)_{x+dx} + \rho v (dxdz)_{y+dy} + (similarly,forZ) = \rho u dydz +\frac{\partial \rho u dydz}{\partial x} dx + (similarly,forYandZ)$$
I don’t understand what the “x + dx” subscript means. Is that a Taylor expansion? I’m having a hard time following that step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means "located at the plane $x+dx$", and it really should be applied to the velocity, not the $dydz$.

Your cube has 6 faces.  Flow in the $x$ direction can enter or exit the Control Volume by crossing the plane perpendicular to $x$ direction at location $x$, and also at the location $x+dx$ ($dx$ is the side length of your cube).  Likewise for flow in the $y$ or $z$ directions.

To build the continuity equation, you are counting up all the mass flow rates into and out of the CV.

I think a better way to write your equation is:

$$  \frac{dm_{out}}{dt} = \rho u(x+dx)  dydz + \rho v(y+dy) dxdz +  \rho w(z+dz) dxdy  
        $$

(With the $x+dx$ etc as the argument of the velocities)

Then you also have

$$  \frac{dm_{in}}{dt} = \rho u(x)  dydz + \rho v(y) dxdz +  \rho w(z) dxdy  
        $$

Conservation of Mass requires:

$$  \frac{dm_{in}}{dt} -   \frac{dm_{out}}{dt} =   \frac{dm}{dt}$$

And the mass $m$ inside the CV equals the density times volume:

$$m=\rho \,dxdydz$$

Try to combine these results to get your continuity equation.

Comment: Thank you very much, that really clears things out! ❤️